# Radio Button on click need to change texts individally

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

First of all please visit this fiddle and click on the radio buttons:
http://jsfiddle.net/skfNh

When clicking on the radio button you might have noticed both the texts  in both
`div class='letter'` (with black background-color) changes. I want to do it individually.
I have tried to do with `.each()` function, but didn't work. How can this be done?

Have a glimpse at current jQuery code I am trying with:

```
$(".selections").append("<div class='letter'>A</div>");
$(".one").click(function () {
    $(".letter").text("B");
});
$(".two").click(function () {
    $(".letter").text("A");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to find the `letter` with the clicked radio buttons parent `selections`.

```
$(".selections").append("<div class='letter'>A</div>");
$(".one").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.selections').find('.letter').text("B");
});
$(".two").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.selections').find('.letter').text("A");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D4pxN/)

Comment: I just about to wrote an answer and saw your answer. How could you be that fast? :)

Comment: Please can you explain in short, what is the purpose for using this `.closest()` function?

Comment: `.closest()` will find the closest parent element with the given selecor

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".one, .two").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.hasClass('one') ? 'B' : 'A';
    $this.parent().siblings(".letter").text(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4y5DX/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selections').each(function() {
    var el = $(this),
        _one = el.find('.one'),
        _two = el.find('.two');

    el.append("<div class='letter'>A</div>");

    var letter = el.find('.letter');

    _one.click(function () {
        letter.text("B");
    });

    _two.click(function () {
        letter.text("A");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do this would be to set an id attribute on the letter class. and then doing this:

```
$("#firstletter").text("B");
$("#secondletter").text("B");
```

should replace the:

```
$("letter") calls
```